# FCPX - Large MXF being broken into smaller files

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

Hardware: MacPro (mid-2012)
Software: OS X 10.1 and FCPX 10.1.4.
Camera: XF100

When I import from CF card a single continuous 100min video interview (50mbps/1080/25p) into FCPX it imports as a single MXF file.

When I import the same file from the same CF card to an identical MacPro offsite the single MXF is broken into smaller files.

Can anyone explain this?

Looking to just import the 1 larger file.

Many thanks for any input.

Comment: are you sure both FCPX's are up to date?  I think MXF import was a recent feature.

Comment: yep - both running 10.1.4

Comment: How big are the smaller files on the second machine?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out FCPX displays spanning files AS WELL as a single large file when importing MXF. See example image below.

The 1st file in the browser list is a single clip / full duration.

All subsequent files are chunks of the single larger file.

[image]